# pyspark string to date

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the string to date format,
Date column consist data in such order but this are in string datatype

```
20191130
20191231
```

when using string to date, date should display as

```
2019-11-31
2019-12-31
```

1. I tried this approach but script returned error

   ```
    df = spark.sql('select * from tablename) 
    df2 = df.withColumn('Date', expr("cast(as_of_date,'yyyyMMdd) as date"))
   ```
2. I also tried on this script and it works , however, with this , it is displaying date and time which is not I wanted

   ```
   df2 = df.withColumn("Date",expr("cast(unix_timestamp(as_of_date ,'yyyyMMdd') as date)")).show()
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `to_date`?

```
df2 = df.withColumn('Date', to_date(col('as_of_date'), 'yyyyMMdd'))
```